# Searching numpy array for for pattern

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to find a value in a numpy array given a search pattern. For instance for the given array `a`, I want to retrieve a result of `1` when using the search pattern `s` because `1` is the element at index 0 of `a[:,1]` (=`array([1, 0, 0, 1])`) and the elements of `a[1:,1]` match `s` (i.e. `(a[1:,1] == s).all() == True` => return `a[0,1]`).

Another example would be `s=[1, 0, 1]` for which I would expect a search result of `2` (match at 4th column starting (1-based)). `2` would also be the search result for `s=[2, 0, 0]`, etc.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> s = np.asarray([0, 0, 1])
```

I came up with `a[0, np.where((a[1:,:].transpose() == s).all(axis=-1))[0][0]]`, but thought there must be something more elegant...

Additionally, it would be great if I could do this operation with one call on multiple search patters, so that I retrieve the 0-element for which the values of index 1 to index 3 match.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the multiple search patterns question? How are those multiple search patterns stored - as 2D array? Add a sample case on it maybe.

Comment: Yes, as 2D array. For instance, I would alter the search array to `s=[[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]` and expect an array as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Single search pattern**

Here's one approach with help from [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) -

```
a[0,(a[1:] == s[:,None]).all(0)]
```

**Multiple search patterns**

For multiple search patterns (stored as 2D array), we just need to `broadcast` as before and look for `ANY` match at the end -

```
a[0,((a[1:] == s[...,None]).all(1)).any(0)]
```

Here's a sample run -

```
In [327]: a
Out[327]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

In [328]: s
Out[328]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0]])

In [329]: a[0,((a[1:] == s[...,None]).all(1)).any(0)]
Out[329]: array([2, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work for the simple query. I've updated my question as I realised the answer to the simple query would not necessarily work for a "batch" query. Any chance you could look at it again?

Comment: I see that it's working, but why is the last `any(0)` required?

Comment: @orange Until the stage of `all(1)`, we would have one 1D array for each pattern. We need `ANY` thereafter to find basically do OR-ing that is give us all columns where the first or second or so on (either one/any) of those patterns are found. This gives us a 1D mask of valid columns to be selected off `a`. From the selected columns, we get the first index element

Comment: Thanks, makes perfectly sense now.